# MySql Match() Against() return all rows containg a word

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently use the following query to get search results, and it works ok.

`select name from table where MATCH(name) AGAINST(:searchTerm IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Thing is, if a row contained a word `MariaDb`, and a user search for `Maria`, it'll return no results. How is it possible to do a search query that'll return all rows containing the words `Maria`?

Users can also search for multiple words like `Computer software`

Comment: Do by any chance 50 percent or more of your records contain the word `Maria`?

Comment: No, there's only one row with the name `MariaDB`

Comment: How do you define `searchItem`? In double quotes or single quotes?

Comment: @PM77-1 I use nothing. See the sql I've posted above? It's the same thing. I'm using PDO to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the operators as you can see in this link:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html
So, change your search term acording with the operators that you need.
Your example would be:

To match MariaDB with Maria word, your search term should be: maria*

```
select name from table where MATCH(name) AGAINST('maria*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```